# How to close connection mysql, mysql.h in c++?

Tags: c++, mysql

How to close connection in c++ when im using mysql.h library?

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "admin", "uczelnia", 3306, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but this is not an issue a skim through the headers wouldn't have solved.

Comment: What does the [***documentation***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) say?

Comment: Its okay. I know but im newbie and i trying fix bugs solo but when i cannot i ask here

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks evidence of any research by the OP for such a simple task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close your connection you would use [`mysql_close`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-close.html)

```
MYSQL* conn;
conn = mysql_init(0);
conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "admin", "uczelnia", 3306, NULL, 0);
mysql_close(conn);
```

> **Description**
>
> Closes a previously opened connection. `mysql_close()` also deallocates the connection handler pointed to by mysql if the handler was allocated automatically by `mysql_init()` or `mysql_connect()`. Do not use the handler after it has been closed.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer!